# Open PDF-File in Android not working

Tags: android, pdf

I try to open a pdf file from my apps directory through a pdf viewer on the device.

```
PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
String s = getPackageName();
                PackageInfo p;
                try {
                    p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0);
                     s = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {                     
                    Log.w("Error", "Error Package not found ", e);                     
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(s + "\\Document.pdf"));
intent.setType("application/pdf");                  
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();                    
Intent crC = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File"); startActivity(crC);
```

On the test device is an pdf viewer installed. Nevertheless I'm told that no existing app is able to open that file. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If anybody is still interested, here is my solution:

I simply changed the code from this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(s + "\\Document.pdf"));
intent.setType("application/pdf");
```

to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(s + "\\Document.pdf"), "application/pdf");
```

And suddenly it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the following code supposed to do?

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();                    
Intent crC = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File"); startActivity(crC);
```

I assume you looked at a few tutorials and got a mixture of everything in here. Instead of those two lines, just try

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Does that not work?

Comment: This line  
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
is unnecessary, you're right :). With the chooser I wanted to get all possible apps that would open the file.

Comment: When I delete the chooser line an activitynotfoundexception appears (no activity found to handle intent), as I expected.

Comment: Hm... given that the mimetype is set, I'd expect at least the correct app to be opened. Can you open PDFs downloaded from the internet?

Comment: Yes, I can... Maybe the PDF-App ("PDF Viewer" from HTC) is not responding correctly? Probably not...

Comment: I can't add comments to your answer. The reason setDataAndType works is because of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType(java.lang.String) . Essentially, setType will reset any data set before it, so if you want to set data AND type, you would want to use setDataAndType.